# Laravel 4.2 SQS queue execute listener in background using code

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am using `Laravel 4.2`.

I am working on a project in which user uploads videos. To make the uploaded video available to all type of devices, I am using `php-ffmpeg` package to `transcode` it. The transcoding process is time consuming that I decided to move it into background and for that I have implemented queue mechanism using `Amazon SQS`.

I have configured the `SQS` driver and key, secrete key, URL as well as region in the `queue.php` file.

For testing purpose only, I have added following code in `Routes.php`.

```
Route::get('/testasync/{id}', function($id){ 
    Queue::push(function($job) use ($id) { 
        try{ 
            $video_rel = VideoRel::find($id); 
            $video_rel->delete();
        } catch(Exception $ex){ 

        } 
        $job->delete(); 
    }); 
    return "hello 1234 world " . $id; 
});
```

So, whenever I will make a get request to `http://mydomainname/testasync/{id}` it will push a message to queue to delete that specific record from a specific model.

Surprisingly, I found the queue will **NOT** be executed until I execute the `queue listener` on the server.

What if I need to do some operation on the server (for example deploy new code etc.). In that case I must have to stop the listener.

Also, another difficulty I found is whenever I re-execute the listener, it is trying to execute all the jobs.

For example, I made two Get request for Id 1 and 2. So both records are deleted. Now I stopped listener for some reason and then made request again for Id 3. Now the record 3 will not be deleted until I execute the listner using `php artisan queue:listen` and if I execute it, it throws 2 error that `method delete called on non-object for Id 1 and 2`; and deletes the record with Id 3.

I am not sure why it happened, as the already executed job must be deleted.

Can anybody have solution??

**It is better to execute listener from code as well as stop it once the job is completed.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you were expecting, but when you do a Queue::push, you're sending the job to the queue and it will only be executed by the listener. If you do not have the queue:listen command on, it will not run. If you want the job to be executed immediately you shouldn't sent it to a queue.

You don't need to stop the listener, you can run it inside a supervisor process and it will automatically restart the process after timeouts. Check this: http://posts.danharper.me/laravel-queue-supervisor/

Now the fact that after you turn off the queue:listen it tries to execute jobs already processed seems really strange to me, it can be that the jobs are not being deleted (try moving the job delete to the beginning of the closure), but I will need more information to help you debug that.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I think if there is an exception while processing code that is in queue, the job was not getting deleted. So that whenever I start queue listener it was trying to execute the jobs that were with exception. I have purged the queue on Amazon and tried again by putting $job->delete() on the top, it worked successfully.

Comment: But, how to maintain the failed queue jobs? For example, due to any error if job fails then re-execute that queue again and if it fails again then delete that job. Is it possible?

Comment: The job->delete() in the top was just a trick. You should only call job->delete() when the job does not fail. Beware that an error of type fatal in php is not caught by the try/catch. If you do not delete the job, the queue will automatically keep processing the job over and over again.
What you can do is only delete de job if no exception was thrown and, at the beginning of the closure you can write:
if ($job->attempts() > 3) {
   $job->delete();
   return;
}

Check this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues

Comment: OK. Another question, where can I put the method Queue::failing()?

Comment: Also how to identify if the Job has failed? For testing failure, I have placed some error prone code in the fire method, the queue listener is throwing exception but I am not finding any entry in failed_jobs table as well as I have placed Queue::failing method in global.php to send email notification but however it is also not getting called.

Comment: Note that Laravel only considers the job as failing, after trying it several times without being able to complete it and delete it. Only after this number of attempts (which I'm not sure about how much it is by default in Laravel, but you can configure it in the listener or in the config) will it insert an entry in the failed_jobs table.
Check this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#failed-jobs